# Fuelphp belongs to relationship, different models

Tags: php, mysql, orm, fuelphp

Using fuelphp's ORM, is it possible to have in a model a field parent_id and another field parent_type and then create a belongs_to relationship where the parent_id may be from a Model_A Model_B or Model_C with th model type stored in parent_type?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but you might be able to work around it using three relationship definitions with a where condition that filters on the parent_type value.

Note that conditions currently only work on eager loading.